# How can I refer to the input field while using jQuery's UI autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I have a form with many inputs, all of them with the class "field". On my JavaScript file, I have something like this:

```
$(".field").autocomplete({
    source:"search.php",
    select:function(event,ui){$(???).doStuff();}
    });
```

What I need is some way to refer to the input field where the user is writing (that is, some selector in place of the "???"), so that I can do some stuff with the surrounding elements. I am guessing that the answer is something like "ui.field", "ui.input" or "ui.element", but I tried those and others with no luck, and I couldn't find the answer in the documentation nor here, so I turn to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `this` (that's the raw element, not wrapped), as with most jQuery events. This could be documented better. :-) So in your case:

```
$(".field").autocomplete({
    source:"search.php",
    select:function(event,ui){
        // Here, `this` is the raw DOM element of the field
        $(this).doStuff();
    }
});
```

Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/usaqox)):

HTML:

```
<p>Type a <kbd>t</kbd> then pick a choice. The field will turn green briefly.</p>
<input class="ac" type="text">
<input class="ac" type="text">
<input class="ac" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".ac").autocomplete({
    source: ["two", "three", "thirty"],
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css("color", "green");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.css("color", "");
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this.id would do the trick here.

```
$(".field").autocomplete({
source:"search.php",
select:function(event,ui){$("#" + this.id).doStuff();}
});
```

Comment: You don't need `id` (and the element may not have one), `this` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ui.item (ui.item.value, ui.item.id etc)?

Comment: `ui.item` is the [selected item](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select), not the input field.